# ABAddressBookAddRecord add once deleted Contact fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to remove a contact from Addressbook and then add it again. 
The deletion is ok but I'm not able to add it. No Errors. 
A new created Contact ( ABPersonCreate(); ) works.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab);
ABRecordRef contact = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allContacts, 0);

ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressBook, contact, nil);
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil);

BOOL addSuccess = ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, contact, &error)
// addSuccess == YES, 
// error == null

BOOL saveSuccess = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error)
// saveSuccess == YES
// error == null
```

The Contact was not added! Why?

Comment: Please look at the code you posted again. It doesn't make sense. What is "test" and we never see what "allPeople" is.

Comment: sorry, copy&paste fail, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try the below procedure:

- Get the contact details (i.e. what you did when calling "**CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allContacts, 0)**").
- Create a new contact (lets name it contact2), and copy the details you got to the new contact (using commands "**ABRecordSetValue(contact2, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR("MyFirstName"), &Error)**", etc ...).
- delete the 1st contact (contact).
- save the addressbook.
- add contact2 to the addressbook.
- save the addressbook.

Hope it helps.

Comment: how do I get all properties? kABPersonFirstNameProperty... and user defined so contact2 has the same details?

Comment: ABRecordSetValue(contact2, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR([contact valueForProperty:kABPersonFirstNameProperty]), &Error)

Propertiy list can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Miscellaneous/AddressBook_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003952-CH3g-SW10